# Determine size of std::array return type without a function call

Tags: c++, templates, decltype, stdarray, type-deduction

I have a class `B` that takes classes like `A` as a template parameter.

```
template<typename T>
class B{
///...
```

Each `T` has an `operator()()` that returns an `std::array<double, N>`. I would like each specialization `B<T>` to be able to deduce `N` without additional requirement on the `T`s and without calling the `operator()()`. How can I do this?

An example `T` is below and labelled as `class A`:

```
template <int N>
class A {
public:
    A() {}

    std::array<double, N> operator()() {
        std::array<double, N> the_integers;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            the_integers[i] = i;
        }
        return the_integers;
    }
};
```

Comment: Use `decltype`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a member to `B`, like this

```
static constexpr std::size_t ArraySize = std::tuple_size_v<decltype(std::declval<T&>()())>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bjTjxzjsK)

Comment: `decltype(std::declval<T&>()()){} . size()` also seems to work (since it's `constexpr`).

Comment: @chi that would actually create a temporary array and value initialize every single element.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili True, but since it's a constexpr variable, there shouldn't be any impact at run-time at least, so as long as `T` is a complete type, chi's solution should be the same.

Comment: @cigien not really. If `operator()` of type `T` returns something that does not have a constexpr constructor, like `array<string, 42>`, it won't be constexpr https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jr73qhTdn

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Oh, I see. Yeah, if it compiles, then there shouldn't be any difference, but using `.size()` may fail to compile in cases that we want it to compile.

Comment: Yes, if you make it constexpr, it won't compile. If you don't, it will a have runtime impact. I wonder why `array::size` isn't a static function.