# How do you use std::declval find the return value of a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, types, decltype

I have a class `B` that takes a template argument such as `A`. I create a `B b` and call `B::operator()(A a)`. Regardless of the type of `a`, `b(a)` should return a double. I would like to deduce this **from outside of** `B` using `decltype`.

If I had a function `B::operator()()`, I could do that with

```
std::declval<B&>()()
```

This was presented to me in my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67808976/determine-size-of-stdarray-return-type-without-a-function-call/67809069#67809069). (Note, `A` and `B` in this question do not match `A` and `B` in the previous question.)

If I had a function `B::operator()(int i)` (no template), I could do that with

```
std::declval<B>()(int())
```

although this appears to only work because `int` is default constructible.

How do I do it when `B::operator()()` is a template function?

Below is some starting code that compiles on my machine. You shouldn't need to look at it to understand the question.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class B {
public:
    B() {};

    template<typename T>
    double operator()(T t) {
        return t();
    }

};

class A {
public:
    A() {};

    double operator()() {
        return 3;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a{};
    B b{};
    std::cout << b(a);

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

To clarify, I want to add a line like

```
using custom_typename = double;
```

to the above code, except, instead of `double`, I write something like

```
using custom_typename = decltype(std::declval<B>()());
```

modified appropriately to take the return type of `B::operator()(T t)` instead of `B::operator()()`.

Comment: If there is a solution that does not use ```std::declval```, that works, and I can edit the question accordingly.

Comment: If you look back to your last question -- it's `decltype` that determines a type, not `std::declval`.  You may not be getting answers because this question presumes that `std::declval` "finds a type".  It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Why write `b.operator()(a)` and not `b(a)`, which is the point of the existence of the "operator"?

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm struggling to understand how ```decltype``` and ```declval``` work. I assumed it was clear I would wrap each of my displays in a ```decltype``` afterwards. I was trying to keep notation to a minimum. If you know how to edit the question to make it more clear to people who understand this stuff, please do.

Comment: @molbdnilo that was left-over copy-and-pasted code from when I templated ```operator``` for some reason. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for

```
decltype(std::declval<B>()(std::declval<A>())) c = b(a);
```

Broken down:

```
         std::declval<B>() //pretend there's a B object
                           std::declval<A>() //pretend there's an A object
         std::declval<B>()(std::declval<A>()) //call b(a) with these 
decltype(std::declval<B>()(std::declval<A>())) //tell me the return type
```

Or, if you wanted to hide that verbosity:

```
template<typename T>
using B_return_t = decltype(std::declval<B>()(std::declval<T>()));


B_return_t<A> c = b(a);
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e6e235b47b12cdd

I assume this doesn't count:

```
auto c = b(a);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is nice because it doesn't require an ```A``` to be constructed.

Answer (score 2):

> Regardless of the type of a, b(a) should return a double. I would like to deduce this from outside of B using decltype.

You can't generally deduce the first sentence. It is Turing complete to decide the type of an expression in C++; see this question:

[C++ templates Turing-complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189172/1593077)

If you want to determine type of `b(a)` for a specific `a`, just write: `decltype(b(a))`; and it shouldn't matter whether class `B`'s `operator()` is templated or not.